# sql trim and replace

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Can i trim and replace at the same time a column's name so i can break it down in two parts? The expected result is in nameL and nameR

```
name        nameL    nameR
AB_1X       AB       1X
AXG_3X      AXG      3X
4G_12X      4G       12X
```

Tried using this query:

```
select *,
RIGHT(name, LEN(name)-4) as nameR,
LEFT(name, LEN(name)-4) as nameL
from myTable
```

The problem is that it trims like this:

```
nameL    
AB_
AXG
4G_
```

same for nameR, because i'm taking a fixed size. How can I eliminate "_" and achieve the expected outcome?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to look at using charindex to find out where the _ occurs. Then you can work out and use LEFT and RIGHT to pull each part

Comment: sorry about rateName, forgot to modify my real query. It's fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with combination of `substring` and `charindex` functions:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(name NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('AB_1X'),
('AXG_3X'),
('4G_12X')

SELECT name, 
       SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX('_', name) - 1) nameL,
       SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX('_', name) + 1, LEN(name)) nameR
FROM @t
```

I assume that there is always underscore symbol in `name` column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
SELECT RIGHT(name, LEN(name) - CHARINDEX('_', name)) AS nameR,
    LEFT(name, CHARINDEX('_', name) - 1) AS nameL
FROM myTable
```